# Why I got "Unhandled exception type IOException"

Tags: java, exception, io

I'm studying Java by examples in a book.
I wrote below code and got "Unhandled exception type IOException"
WHY? and HOW could I solve this. Should I declare IOException class?

```
import java.nio.file.*;

public class JavaIO {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String dirString = "C:/Users/USER/Desktop/Test/Files";
        Path dirPath = Paths.get(dirString);
        if(Files.notExists(dirPath)){
            Files.createDirectory(dirPath);
        }       
        System.out.println("Err");
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is most likely due to the fact that you haven't created the directories leading up to "Files", use "createDirectories" instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `Files.createDirectory()` may throw `java.io.IOException` and you did neither catch it nor declare to throw it.

Catch the exception to handle errors

```
import java.nio.file.*;

public class JavaIO {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String dirString = "C:/Users/USER/Desktop/Test/Files";
        Path dirPath = Paths.get(dirString);
        if(Files.notExists(dirPath)){
            try{
                Files.createDirectory(dirPath);
            } catch(java.io.IOException e){
                System.out.println("createDirectory failed:" + e);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Err");
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

or add declaration to throw it to ignore its possibility to be thrown.

```
import java.nio.file.*;

public class JavaIO {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {

        String dirString = "C:/Users/USER/Desktop/Test/Files";
        Path dirPath = Paths.get(dirString);
        if(Files.notExists(dirPath)){
            Files.createDirectory(dirPath);
        }
        System.out.println("Err");
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you!!!!!! I added try catch statement, but the error still occurred. I used java.io.IOException instead of IOException. Thank you!!!!

Comment: @pty115 Add `import java.io.IOException;` and you shouldn't need to fully qualify the class name.

Answer (score 3):

[`Files.createDirectory(Path dir, FileAttribute<?>... attrs)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createDirectory-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...-) throws [`IOException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/IOException.html) which is a *checked* `Exception`; *either* `catch` it or modify `main` to indicate it *might* be thrown. Something like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
```

**or** use a `try-catch` and `catch` the `IOException` like

```
if(Files.notExists(dirPath)){
    try {
        Files.createDirectory(dirPath);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```

Comment: thank you!!!!!! I added try catch statement, but the error still occurred. I used java.io.IOException instead of IOException. Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Look up a Try Catch and place the parts of your code that are dealing with the file inside it. This will handle and report exception if the file cannot be created or the location doesn't exist.

Comment: thank you!!!!!! I added try catch statement, but the error still occurred. I used java.io.IOException instead of IOException. Thank you!!!!

Comment: ohh, that just means that you had to import the java.io.IOException if you wanted to write it shorter in the program.

Answer (score 0):

When you are working with files or performing an IO operation in Java, there is a chance that you will not be able to access the files or resource for various reasons, This will throws a Exception condition on lines of FIleNotFound or IO operation cannot be performed. This Exception need to be handled as it comes under "checked" exception in Java. Simply said you need to either handle this case yourself or let the child classes do it using Throws, throw or try/catch block.

Hence with  "Unhandled exception type IOException" message Java is asking you to do the same.

Comment: then should I handle all possible Exceptions in JAVA? In other programming languages, I didn't need to do that. Is it characteristic of JAVA?

Comment: Not all, just the one you are being asked to, there is a catch all way by using Exception class, this is the parent class of all the "checked" exception.